# Being in Janabah and thinking I cannot fast therefore I may have broken my fast?

Tags: sawm

I am in the process of making up a few fast days however I have a question that I am unsure as to whenever or not I can continue my fast. I have only on the same day learnt that "being in Janabah" does not invalidate your fast' and ghusul is necessary to pray however. Prior to brushing my teeth however I may have knowingly swallowed a TINY bit of water because I was under the belief that I was automatically not permitted to fast. Only after reading that this is in fact permissible am I not sure if my fast is going to be valid and I should continue or if I should break it and start again?  Points to note are:

1. Janabah was prior to the start of the fast
2. I have not eaten or drunken ANYTHING since the start of the fast intentionally or not except the below.
3. The drop of water I *may* have innocently *intentionally* swallowed was due to the fact that I thought I was **not** allowed to fast.
4. I only came to know that being in Janabah would not invalidate your fast **after** Point 3 already occurred.
5. I had every intention (niyah) of fasting before going to sleep the night before the wet dream occurred however was under the thinking that I cannot fast now that this has happened (in the middle of the night I mean).

Thanks